# ConstructorException parsing XML with Retrofit and SimpleXML (Parameter does not have a match)

Tags: kotlin, xml-parsing, retrofit

***SOLUTION IS IN THE FIRST ANSWER**

I'm pretty noob using `SimpleXML Converter` so models and annotations may be wrong.

This is the `XML` I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cards-summary-response xmlns="http:/mywebpage.com/rest-api">
    <card-summary>
        <identifier>51641C1B23931</identifier>
        <display-name>Debit Card</display-name>
        <program-name>plastic_debit</program-name>
        <status>Blocked</status>
    </card-summary>
    <card-summary>
        <identifier>4E1BDFCC1D6</identifier>
        <display-name>Virtual Debit</display-name>
        <program-name>virtual_debit</program-name>
        <status>Active</status>
    </card-summary>
</cards-summary-response>
```

My models:

**CardSummaryResponse.kt**

```
@Root(strict = false, name = "cards-summary-response")
data class CardSummaryResponse constructor(
    @ElementList(
        required = false,
        name = "card-summary",
        entry = "card-summary",
        inline = true,
        empty = true
    )
    var cardsSummaryList: MutableList<CardSummary>? = null
)
```

**CardSummary.kt**

```
@Root(name = "card-summary")
data class CardSummary @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @field:Element(name = "identifier", required = true)
    var identifier: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "status", required = true)
    var status: String = ""
)
```

API configuration:

```
retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict(
            Persister(AnnotationStrategy())
        )
    )
    .baseUrl(CallsConfiguration.BASE_URL_WIRECARD)
    .client(clientBuilder.build())
    .build()
service = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface::class.java)
```

And RetrofitInterface (this class is in Java):

```
@GET("webservices/wd-test.phtml")
Call<CardSummaryResponse> getCardsSummary();
```

I'm always getting the same exception:

> java.lang.Error: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException:
>   Parameter 'card-summary' does not have a match in class
>   com.app.account.model.CardSummaryResponse

Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe its a typo? `@Root(strict = false, name = "card-summary-response")
` should be `cards-summary-response`

Comment: My mistake. But I've fixed it and is still throwing the `Exception`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to make it work using the following models:

**CardSummaryResponse.tk**

```
@Root(strict = false, name = "cards-summary-response")
data class CardSummaryResponse constructor(
    @field:ElementList(
        required = false,
        name = "card-summary",
        entry = "card-summary",
        inline = true,
        empty = true
    )
    var cardsSummaryList: MutableList<CardSummary>? = null
)
```

**CardSummary.tk**

```
@Root(name = "card-summary")
data class CardSummary constructor(
    @field:Element(name = "identifier", required = true)
    var identifier: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "status", required = true)
    var status: String = ""
)
```

Comment: `How we can get attribute like: @Path("enclosure") @param:Attribute(name = "url") var url: String = "", I am getting error: "Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ConstructorException: Parameter 'enclosure[1]/@url' does not have a match in class`

Comment: In case you are having this error: "Empty value for @org.simpleframework.xml.Element...". Use required = false to prevent empty values like: <status></status>

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was using `'val'` in the data class. After spending 3 hours, I found the solution: just replace `'val` with `'var'` and give the `default value.`

Here are my data classes that are working fine after the solution:

```
sealed class Feeds {

@Root(name = "rss", strict = false)
data class RssFeed constructor(@field:Element(name = "channel") var channel: RssChannel? = null) :
    Feeds()

@Root(name = "channel", strict = false)
data class RssChannel constructor(
    @field:ElementList(
        name = "item",
        inline = true,
        required = false
    ) var item: List<RssItem>? = null
) : Feeds()

@Root(name = "item", strict = false)
data class RssItem constructor(
    @field:Element(name = "title") var title: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "description") var description: String = "",
    @field:Element(name = "link") var link: String = ""
) : Feeds()
}
```

Happy Coding!!!